# MySQL timestamp comparison with less than sign

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp, blogs

I made a PHP blog. Everything is up and running except one glitch. I want to display the articles in decreasing order sorted by date. So whenever an article is added to the DB an auto timestamp records the time of insertion.

GLITCH - > i want to display 5 articles per page. I did that easily for the first page by using this

```
$sql="SELECT id,article_name,article_body,date 
         from articles order by date desc limit 5" ;
```

Now i want to proceed with the second page and would like the second page to display the articles from where the page 1 left. If there are 10 articles in descending order, page 1 should display the first 5 and page 2 should display the next five.

This logic should work realtime when many articles are added per day. i used this query but it's displaying just 1 row.

```
$sql="select id,article_name,article_body,unix_timestamp(date) 
           from articles 
           where date < (select unix_timestamp(date)
                 from articles order by date desc limit $n,1 ) 
           order by date desc limit $n,5" ;
```

$n - the id from where the rows will be extracted.

Comment: You would have to put the 'last article id' in the 'next page' link otherwise there is no way to know where to start from.

Comment: I think sel's solution is the best. limit+offset takes care of pagination for you, you don't need to specify where to start. But if you use `< (subquery)` then you should NOT specify `$n` in the outer query -- the less-than already takes care of starting where you left off, the extra `$n` causes it to skip double the number.

Answer (score 2):

utilize the offset in sql:

```
$items_per_page=5;   
$offset=($current_page-1)* $items_per_page;
```

the sql:

```
SELECT id,article_name,article_body,date 
         from articles order by date desc LIMIT  $items_per_page OFFSET $offset
```

Comment: umm.... but i want to get the articles sorted according to date. like the latest article comes first and the older ones comes after that.

Comment: @barmer man your advise helped me a lott ! thanks A TONN man !!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
select id,article_name,article_body,unix_timestamp(date) 
from articles 
where date < ( select date from articles order by date desc limit $n,1 ) 
order by date desc limit $n,5
```

where $n should be the last id from previous page